# Calculating date

Tags: jquery, date, calendar

Currently I am trying to calculate the ending date of a specific event on a calendar using jquery. There are three conditions that are affecting the final date:

- which days of the week the event occurs
- the event repeats every week or every two or three weeks and so on
- the number of times I want the event to occur

So for example, if I have an event that occurs Monday, Wednesday, Friday, every 3 weeks and I only want it to occur 14 times, what would the final date be? So the first Monday would be 1 occurrence then the first Wednesday would be 2 occurrences and so on. How would I create an algorithm that calculates the last date this event occurs?

Comment: @Sumurai8 If the event occurred on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday then the event would occur three Times a week

Answer (score 0):

Besides the 3 things you listed, you also need a starting date. Without a starting date it is impossible to calculate an ending date.

First you need to calculate which days of the event are in the week of the starting date. Then you can use the amount of days of the weeks the event occurs on, and the repetition to calculate which week is the last week the event occurs on. Then you use the days of the week the event occurs on to find the last day it occurs on.

It would look something like the following code. Please note that this doesn't handle situations correctly where you shouldn't go through all the blocks, but I'll leave that as something you have to do yourself.

```js
var now = new Date();
var startdate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());

var eventdays = [1,3,5]; //Monday, Wednesday, Friday
var repetition = 3;
var maxamount = 14;

var oneday = 86400000;

var runningDate = startdate.getTime();

//Which event days are in this week?
for( var i = 0; i < eventdays.length; i++ ) {
  if( eventdays[i] >= startdate.getDay() ) {
    maxamount -= eventdays.length-i;
    break;
  }
}
runningDate += oneday * (7 - startdate.getDay());
//runningDate is now sunday of the next week

var fullperiods = Math.floor( (maxamount-1) / eventdays.length );
runningDate += oneday * 7 * repetition * fullperiods;
maxamount -= fullperiods * eventdays.length;

//The rest of the days
runningDate += oneday * eventdays[maxamount];

console.log( new Date( runningDate ) );
```